# Vim colorscheme for latex: citations vs math

Tags: vim, latex

This is a very specific question. I've discovered that the

```
hi Special guifg=....
```

line in a vim color file controls the color of both math mode like

```
$whatever$
```

and the color of citation names like

```
\cite{whatever}
```

If I change that Special color, whatever in both code snippets changes color. However, I've seen some vim colorschemes where these two colors are different. I want the color of citation and section labels, like \ref{whatsinhere} and \cite{whatsinhere} to be different than $whatsinhere$. Can someone tell me how to do this? I know it can be done; the colorscheme wuye on the following page has such a feature, but I can't find where! http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-tex.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command echoes the syntax group(s) of the word under your cursor:

```
" shows syntaxic group of the word under the cursor
command! SynStack call SynStack()<CR>
function! SynStack()
  if !exists("*synstack")
    return
  endif
  echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

If you are curious, these values are defined in your latex syntax file. On a Unix-based machine, you can find this file here: `/usr/share/vim/vim7x/syntax/tex.vim`.

Supposing the syntax group is `SomeTexKeyword`, you could add a line to your colorscheme:

```
hi SomeTexKeyword ctermbg=...
```

with the colors you want.